# Cassandra table doesn't have tombstones for deleted rows

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I've a simple emp table:

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
  empid int,
  deptid int,
  first_name text,
  last_name text,
  PRIMARY KEY (empid, deptid)
) WITH ...
```

I inserted 10 records. Then deleted 1 record and checked the json for table. It was like following:

```
...
{"key": "0000000a","columns": [["1003:","",1427796440909000], ["1003:first_name","fn10",1427796440909000], ["1003:last_name","ln10",1427796440909000]]},
{"key": "00000001","metadata": {"deletionInfo": {"markedForDeleteAt":1427797012545000,"localDeletionTime":1427797012}},"columns": []},
{"key": "00000008","columns": [["1001:","",1427796419431000], ["1001:first_name","fn8",1427796419431000], ["1001:last_name","ln8",1427796419431000]]},
...
```

So, 1 record is correctly marked for deletion.
Next I deleted all records from the table and `select * from emp` doesn't return anything on `cqlsh` prompt.

However, when I check the json for table, I get the same output as after 1 record deletion. This is a dev environment and entire data was in 1 `sstable`.

Why are tombstones for other deleted records not reflected in json output for the table?

Answer (score 2):

Its in the memtable thats merged with the sstables. Do a `nodetool flush` before the sstable2json to see whats currently in memtable & commit logs.

Comment: The "delete all", depending on how it's done, may be a range tombstone